# Print html page in vb.net windows application

Tags: .net, html, vb.net

I have a simple html page with place holders in it, when the user fill some info i replace these info in the html page and then print this page, my question is how to print an html page with its embedded format?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you "holding" the html page in memory?  Or are you trying to print the file?

Comment: basically I am using stream reader to hold the content and do the replaces.

Comment: i can use another way i don't mind if you have any

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Print html page in vb.net windows application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278551/how-to-print-html-page-in-vb-net-windows-application)

Answer (score 0):

One of your best options would be to put a WebBrowser control on your form.  It can be hidden if you want.  After saving the StreamWriter

```
        strWriter = New IO.StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath & filename & ".html")
        strWriter.Write(docStuff)
        strWriter.Close()
```

Then just reload the file into the WebBrowser, and tell it to Print.  Fairly simple.  If you want to get away from the WebBrowser control, then you are going to have to use System.Diagnostics.Process.  For example, the following line will open the html file in your default Browser.  You are able to add arguments to this statement to get it to print, but you would have to experiment to see what argument you need to get it to autoprint.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath & fileName & ".html")
```

An even easier option is to use ProcessStartInfo.  You need to Import System.Diagnostics to do this...

```
    Dim proStart As New ProcessStartInfo
    proStart.FileName = filepathAndName
    proStart.Verb = "print"
    Process.Start(proStart)
```