# How to Print html page in vb.net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, html, vb.net, winforms

I am developing a windows application using vb.net, I have a simple html page with place holders in it, I load the page into a stream reader, replace the place holders and then I need to print the html content, anybody have any idea how to print the html content as html and not source.
P.S. code in vb.bet or c# is ok.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `WebBrowser` control to do so. It will allow you to show HTML inside your `WinForms`.

The DocumentText proprety will allow you to set a String that represent the HTML you want to show.

For example:

```
webBrowser.DocumentText = "<html><body><p>I like StackOverflow</p><body></html>";
```

Afterward if you want to print the page, you'll have to wait until the Document is completed and call the `Print` method of the `WebBrowser`. MSDN shows an easy way to do it:

```
private void PrintHelpPage()
{
    // Create a WebBrowser instance. 
    WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();

    // Add an event handler that prints the document after it loads.
    webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted +=
        new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocument);

    // Set the Url property to load the document.
    webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(@"\\myshare\help.html");
}

private void PrintDocument(object sender,
    WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Print the document now that it is fully loaded.
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();

    // Dispose the WebBrowser now that the task is complete. 
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
}
```

You should also consider trying to use the method `PrintDialog` to make sure the issue is not your printing configuration.

Here is the link to MSDN:
[Print with a WebBrowser control on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0wes9a3.aspx)

Possible duplicate:
[Printing WebBrowser control content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610183/printing-webbrowser-control-content)

Comment: I tried this but when trying to call webbroswer1.print nothing is happening.

Comment: You mean you want to physically print the HTML you rendered?

Comment: I edited my answer to reflect your question, it is strongly recommended to add Code Snippets of what you already have tried and so on to your question. Also, I found several duplicate of your question on StackOverflow, you should consider being more thorough with your search next time.

Comment: @PeekaySwitch am investigating into this to see if i can set the printer name instead of using windows default printer. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I use the next code. Big problem I had with change page orientation, only working solution is to change page settings on default printer, direct registry hack is used.

```
Sub printHTMLFile (FileName As String, Portrait As Boolean, Copies As Integer)
  Const PAGESET_KEY As String = "Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\PageSetup"

  If Copies < 1 Then Exit Sub
  Dim MyKey As RegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey (PAGESET_KEY, True)
  Dim TempFooter As String = MyKey.GetValue ("footer").ToString ()
  Dim TempHeader As String = MyKey.GetValue ("header").ToString ()
  Dim TempBottom As String = MyKey.GetValue ("margin_bottom").ToString ()
  Dim TempLeft   As String = MyKey.GetValue ("margin_left").ToString ()
  Dim TempRight  As String = MyKey.GetValue ("margin_right").ToString ()
  Dim TempTop    As String = MyKey.GetValue ("margin_top").ToString ()
  MyKey.SetValue ("footer", String.Empty)
  MyKey.SetValue ("header", String.Empty)
  MyKey.SetValue ("margin_bottom", "0.40000")
  MyKey.SetValue ("margin_left",   "0.40000")
  MyKey.SetValue ("margin_right",  "0.40000")
  MyKey.SetValue ("margin_top",    "0.40000")
  MyKey.Close ()
  pageSet (Portrait)

  Dim WB As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser ()
  WB.Navigate (FileName)
  While WB.ReadyState <> WebBrowserReadyState.Complete
    'Thread.Sleep (100)
    Application.DoEvents ()
  End While
  For i As Integer = 1 To Copies
    WB.Print ()
  Next

  MyKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey (PAGESET_KEY, True)
  MyKey.SetValue ("footer",        TempFooter)
  MyKey.SetValue ("header",        TempHeader)
  MyKey.SetValue ("margin_bottom", TempBottom)
  MyKey.SetValue ("margin_left",   TempLeft)
  MyKey.SetValue ("margin_right",  TempRight)
  MyKey.SetValue ("margin_top",    TempTop)
  MyKey.Close ()
End Sub

Sub pageSet (Portrait As Boolean)
' page orientation settins on default printer
  Const DEVICE_KEY = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Windows"
  Const DEVMODE_KEY = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Printers\DevModePerUser"
  Const DEFAULT_DEVMODE_KEY = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Printers\"

  Dim DevStr As String = Registry.GetValue (DEVICE_KEY, "Device", String.Empty)
  Dim PrinterName As String = DevStr.Substring (0, (DevStr.IndexOf (",")))

  Dim DevMode() As Byte = Registry.GetValue (DEVMODE_KEY, PrinterName, Nothing)
  If DevMode Is Nothing Then
    DevMode = Registry.GetValue (DEFAULT_DEVMODE_KEY & PrinterName.Replace ("\"c, ","c), "Default DevMode", Nothing)
  End If
  If Portrait Then
    DevMode(76) = 1
  Else
    DevMode(76) = 2
  End If
  Registry.SetValue (DEVMODE_KEY, PrinterName, DevMode)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

On [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9d1a59c9-0e3c-4221-9fbe-6217dc8d3c84/how-to-better-print-a-rendered-html-document-in-vbnet-this-code-works-but-i-dont-like-it?forum=Vsexpressvb) page, I found a great compact solution that's really easy to implement:

```
Dim printProcess As New Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
printProcess.FileName = "YOUR_FILE_HERE.html"
printProcess.Verb = "print"
'printProcess.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
Process.Start(printProcess)
```

Hope its useful to future visitors of this page!

Answer (score 0):

For those who may find this simple VB code helpful, I print my html template documents like this:

```
Dim PrintWebBrowser As New WebBrowser
AddHandler PrintWebBrowser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf DocumentCompleted
PrintWebBrowser.DocumentText = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC etc. etc. </html>"    

Private Sub DocumentCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    With DirectCast(sender, WebBrowser)
        If .ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
            .Print()
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```